# If $a$ has order $p$ and $aPa^{-1}=P$ then $a\in P$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> If $G$ is a finite group, $P$ a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, $a\in G$ has order $p$ and $aPa^{-1}=P$ then $a\in P$.

This is proved in Rotman:

Proof: We have $a\in N_G(P)$. If $a\notin P$ then $aP\in N_G(P)/P$ has order $p$, which contradicts $N_G(P)/P$ is prime to $p$.

I don't see why $aP$ has order $p$ in the quotient. Of course $a^pP=P$. But why if $1<n<p$ can't we have $a^n\in P$?

Thank you.

Comment: If $a^n\in P$ for some $n<p$, then $(n,p)$ are coprime - can you see what this might force?

Comment: @Talexius the if $a^m=1$ then order of $a$ divides $m$.

Comment: Since $a^p=1$, also $(aP)^p=a^pP=P$. Since $aP\ne P$, you can conclude that the order of $aP$ in $N_G(P)/P$ is $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:G\rightarrow H$ is a groups morphism then $order(f(x))$
divides $order(x)=m$, because $f(x)^m=f(x^m)=f(e)=e$. So $aP$ has
order $1$ or $p$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof without an appeal to modding out a normalizer by its Sylow subgroup: since $aPa^{-1}=P$, the subset $P\langle a \rangle$ is actually a *subgroup* containing $P$. Since $|P\langle a \rangle|=\frac{|P| \cdot |\langle a \rangle|}{|P \cap \langle a \rangle|}$ is a power of $p$, and $P$ is Sylow, whence a *maximal* $p$-subgroup, we must have $P\langle a \rangle=P$, that is, $a \in P$. This shows by the way that the order of $a$ can be *any* power of $p$ to make the statement true.